# Find a modulus of continuity for $f(x,y)=\sqrt{1+x^2+2y^2}$.

Tags: real-analysis

Find a modulus of continuity for the function $f(x,y)=\sqrt{1+x^2+2y^2}$.

Not sure how to approach this kind of question for multivariate function, seems algebraically complicated.  Can I get a solution and some tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2$, you have
$$\begin{aligned}
\left\vert \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y) \right\vert &= \frac{\vert x \vert}{\sqrt{1+x^2+2y^2}} \le 1\\
\left\vert\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)\right\vert &= \frac{2 \vert y \vert}{\sqrt{1+x^2+2y^2}} \le \sqrt{2}\\
\end{aligned}$$

Hence $\vert \nabla f(x,y)\vert \le \sqrt{2}$ for all $(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2$.

Then using the [Mean value theorem for several variables in several variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Mean_value_theorem_for_vector-valued_functions), you get
$$\vert f(x_1,y_1) - f(x_2,y_2) \vert \le \sqrt{2} \Vert (x_1,y_1) - (x_2,y_2) \Vert \tag{1}$$

for all $(x_1,y_1), (x_2,y_2) \in \mathbb R^2$. That proves that $\omega$ is a [modulus of continuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulus_of_continuity) with $\omega: x \mapsto \sqrt{2} x$.

Comment: Is going from line 2 to line 3 correct?

Comment: Sure as $(x_1^2-x_2^2) + 2 (y_1^2 - y_2^2) \le 2(x_1^2-x_2^2) + 2 (y_1^2 - y_2^2)$. And then factor number $2$.

Comment: Sorry doesn't this assume that $x_1^2-x_2^2$ is positive?

Comment: @helios321 This is a good point. I'll delete the answer and come back with another approach using MVT.

Comment: @helios321 Thanks for noticing my error. I updated the answer using MVT.

Comment: Hey, thanks I get it, though the book hadn't covered MVT for several variables yet, but I get the idea.  One thing:  did you mean  $\omega: x \mapsto x/ \sqrt{2}$?

Comment: @helios321 No considering equation $(1)$, the modulus of continuity is $\omega: x \mapsto \sqrt{2} x$.